# How do I use Bootstrap Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap Validation so what I did was copied the code from [here](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) and tried to get it to work in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7X9mG/). The issue that I am running into is that the validation that tells you only to select 2 choices does not show up here is what the tutorial suggested that I use:

```
<input type="checkbox"
name="qualityControl[]"
value="fast"
minchecked="2"
data-validation-minchecked-message="Choose two"
maxchecked="2"
data-validation-maxchecked-message=
"You can't have it all ways"
>
```

I did that and plugged in the `submit` JQuery and still get nothing when I select 3 also nothing turns yellow. I do get a cool popup identifier which tells me that I am close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required to include `jQuery` and initialize `jqBootstrapValidation` i.e.

```
  $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7X9mG/2/

Comment: What did I leave out?

Comment: jquery library and the code posted. Try to check the browser's console for errors, when coding.

Comment: Thanks...I am wanting to use this in a custom DotNetNuke module as well as in some . In DNN the JQuery Library is added automatically. I totally looked over this in the JSFiddle. Thanks a ton!